# Matlab Loop of all combinations

Tags: matlab, loops

Im new to Matlab and this seems to be beyond me.  Appreciate the help and thanks in advance.

1. Basically, I have a multiple columns dataset with column headers.  Column numbers could vary from dataset to dataset.
2. Need to iterate through all the combinations of columns (eg A+B, A+C....B+C, B+D...etc) and run a formula (in this instance it is a correlation formula but could be another formula subsequently).
3. If particular combination returns "true", then the column headers of the pair will be returned.

Would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could use combntns: http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/map/ref/combntns.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nchoosek` to get all pairs of columns:

```
pairs_columns = nchoosek(1:m, 2);
pairs = {};

for pair = 1:size(pairs_columns,1)
    flag = your_correlation_test(data(:,pairs_columns(pair,1)), data(:,pairs_columns(pair,2)));
    if flag
        pairs{end+1,1} = data_header(pairs_columns(pair,1));
        pairs{end,2} = data_header(pairs_columns(pair,2));      %// Note that you don't need end+1 anymore as the previous line will have already increased the number of rows in the vector
    end
end
```

`m` is your number of columns

`your_correlation_test` is your test function that returns a Boolean result

`data` is your dataset (which I'm assuming you can index by column number?)

`data_header` is a place holder for whatever the correct way to get the header is from your dataset based on the column number. Sorry I'm not very familiar with datasets in Matlab

Comment: Dear Dan, thanks for such a detailed reply. Really appreciate it!  It now makes sense when I see your code.