# Loop through all combinations of 8 in 15 MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

I have this matrix and want to make all combinations of column composed square matrixes (8x8) composed from this data.

```
  4  2  4   3   2   3   3   2   8   4   9   7   6   6   6
  2  0  4   1   0   3   0   8   5   0   9   3   7   7   1
  2  1  2   1   1   3   1   4   5   2   4   2   6   6   3
  0  0  2   2   1   2   3   9   1   1   4   4   4   4   6
  4  0  1   0   4   2   3   1   8   1   3   0   5   5   7
  3  1  4   0   0   1   0   2   6   2   9   1   2   2   0
  1  2  1   4   0   3   4   1   3   4   3   9   7   7   9
  2  0  0   4   0   0   3   1   5   0   1   9   1   1   7
```

Even after reeding [Matlab Loop of all combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536771/matlab-loop-of-all-combinations)
I'm not really sure how to do all the matrix combinations and include the counter from the for loop in the name of the combination obtained in the itteration.

Comment: Is the order of columns in the matrix important?

Comment: I assumed it wasn't important in my answer because you asked about combinations not permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called your matrix `A`.

```
p=nchoosek(1:15,8);
```

gives all the combinations of 8 numbers taken from 1 to 15. These represent the columns of the matrix `A` that you want.

There are now 3 ways to proceed. Firstly, using a `for` loop:

```
M=zeros(8,8,size(p,1));
for i=1:size(p,1)
    M(:,:,i)=A(:,p(i,:));
end
```

which puts each 8x8 matrix into a larger 3D array. You would get out individual matrices by doing `M(:,:,54)`, for example.

You can also create a cell array:

```
N=arrayfun(@(k) A(:,p(k,:)),1:size(p,1),'UniformOutput',false);
```

and get individual matrices by doing `N{54}`.

Finally, you could not precompute each matrix, and just pull out the appropriate columns when you need them. This may be the most efficient method if you don't reuse the matrices:

```
O=A(:,p(54,:));
```